# how is classpath resolved in tomcat6 when using a custom Realm?

Tags: tomcat, classpath

I have a custom realm in tomcat6 which is deployed and using jars in the tomcat/lib directory.  I would like to move those jars out of tomcat/lib into their separate shared folder of some sort, as I think they may be conflicting with the jars of a WAR.

I tried setting shared.loader to 
    ${catalina.base}/shared/lib,${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar

However, the realm fails to find the jars.  Since I don't know the logic for Realm classpaths I tried setting server.loader to also point to my shared lib, but that didn't help any.  I'm not sure if I have something wrong with the shared lib, or if the Realm's classpath is resolved in a different manner and so ignores these arguments?

Comment: Where are the Realm classes? Where are the dependent classes? What error do you get? Why can't you put everything into `${catalina.base}/lib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat's `shared` ClassLoader is not what you want: that one is for sharing libraries across web applications. Instead, you want the `server` ClassLoader. Note that the `server` ClassLoader's default setting is that of the `common` ClassLoader, so you'll need to copy the existing setting from `common.loader` into `server.loader` and then add your own JAR file to it.

Honestly, if you have a custom realm that is conflicting with one of your web applications, you should probably just fix the web application and/or the Realm.

Comment: I'm not too surprised that it's the server.loader that Realm uses.  However, as I said I set that value as well and it didn't work.  I tried copying the stuff from common.loader into the path of server.loader, but I had the same issue, the Realm can't find the jars in server.loader.  and we *are* removing the Realm, but it's not due to be replaced until end of december, and this release has to go out the beggining of December.